# cmake Eigen find_package HINTS

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I need to add [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) to one of our projects. 
Since Eigen is header-only we decided to put it directly into our source-code directory to track it with Git and make sure that everything is ready as soon as you clone the repository. 
Therefore, we downloaded Eigen from [here](http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.7.tar.bz2) and placed it in the directory `EIGEN` inside our project directory.

We are using `cmake` in this project. 
I can include Eigen using the following code:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
if (Eigen3_FOUND)
    message("Eigen found")
    message("  Eigen location: ${Eigen3_DIR}")
    message("  Eigen Version: ${Eigen3_VERSION}")
    target_link_libraries (ourProject Eigen3::Eigen)
endif ()
```

However, this code does find a different Eigen version located in `/usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake`.

I want it to use the Eigen version located in the source-code directory. 
Therefore, I tried to use the `HINTS` option:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED HINTS ./EIGEN)
```

but it does not work. 
My main problem is that I do not know which path I have to write into the HINTS. 
The EIGEN directory contains multiple other folders. I tried some of them but with no luck:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED HINTS ./EIGEN/Eigen)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED HINTS ./EIGEN/Eigen/src)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED HINTS ./EIGEN/cmake)...
```

What is the correct way to make ensure that cmake does use the Eigen version I want?

Comment: Have you considered finding the Eigen repo using `add_subdirectory(EIGEN)`?

Comment: "Therefore, I tried to use the HINTS option ... but it does not work." - Description "it does not work" is not very helpful. What **exactly** you observe with this attempt? Does result of `find_package` not changed? Or does CMake emit an error?

Comment: @Tsyvarev it does not change the Eigen version which is selected. It always selects the `/usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like squareskittles mentioned in the comments, you should call `add_subdirectory()` with the location of Eigen3 in your source tree. You then won't need to call `find_package()`, as long as you are only using the `Eigen3::Eigen` target as this will be added by the Eigen3 CMake scripts.

So if you had the following source tree:

```
- foo/
  - CMakeLists.txt    # Top-level CMakeLists file
  - eigen/            # Cloned Eigen repo
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - ...
  - foo.cpp
  - foo.hpp
```

Your foo/CMakeLists.txt should contain:

```
add_subdirectory(eigen)
```

Be wary though, some CMake variables may not be set without calling `find_package()` - *Eigen3_VERSION* and *Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIR* for example. If you do decide to call `find_package()` to get these, you don't need to give it a HINTS parameter, and can provide CONFIG or NO_MODULE to go straight into Config mode.

Then CMake will search for an **Eigen3Config.cmake** instead of a **FindEigen3.cmake**, which will be generated in the Eigen build tree.

Comment: If Eigen is added via `add_subdirectory()`, the Eigen source would essentially be part of your current project (and current CMake invocation), and the Eigen targets/variables can be referenced out-right. In that case, you wouldn't need `find_package()` at all, correct?

Comment: @squareskittles You are indeed correct. The `Eigen3::Eigen` target will be added whether you call `find_package()` or not. However in "non-modern" CMake where we used `include_directories` with **<package>_INCLUDE_DIR**, this won't work as this variable isn't added until the *Config.cmake file is processed from what I have seen so far. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Pesho_T I tried to use `add_subdirectoy()` but it did not work. I tried it this way: `add_subdirectory(EIGEN/Eigen)` and get the following error message: CMake Error at EIGEN/Eigen/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    RegexUtils ...

Comment: @user7431005 Do you have an EIGEN directory at the same directory level as the CMakeLists.txt file you added `add_subdirectory()` to, and does it contain an Eigen directory which contains a CMakeLists.txt file? Check out [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_subdirectory.html) about the command in question and my latest edit, that should hopefully be enough to get you going.

Comment: @Pesho_T I am currently obtaining the Eigen library using `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`, but as you observed it does not define variables such as Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIR. To solve this issue I added the line `find_package(Eigen3 3.4.0 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)` just after `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`. Is this the right solution? Or is there a better way to make the fetched content available along with the CMake variables defined in **Eigen3Config.cmake**? Thanks a lot for any help you can provide!

Comment: @fdev The problem with calling `find_package()` with the args above is that it will look for Eigen's config script in directories predetermined by CMake (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) and it's unlikely it'll find the one built by your project. Also I don't know how Eigen is configured, but the files required for find_package to work may not be availeble until later. What exactly are you trying to achieve? If Eigen is being built in your project it's likely you can find what you're looking for in other ways.

Comment: @Pesho_T Thank you for your answer! Basically, I am using `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` to get Eigen. After that, I use `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` to get another library that also uses Eigen, but that finds Eigen through the command `find_package`. However, by doing so, it finds the system version of Eigen (I know that by printing the variable `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR`), which is older (3.3.x) compared to the one I am fetching (3.4.0). So, later, when I use `Eigen3::Eigen` in `target_link_libraries` for some targets, I wonder which version of Eigen I am actually employing. How do I know it?

Comment: @fdev no worries! You could always get `Eigen3::Eigen`'s properties and print out the location of it to figure out what the location of the library is. As of how to make sure the one you want gets picked up instead of the system Eigen, consider posting a new question as the comments isn't a great place to post solution to new problems :)